# Reading in a MIDI file as a hex string: missing some information

Tags: c++, hex, midi

I have a MIDI file which I am trying to read as a hex string: in particular I want to input a MIDI file and to have the hex string available for use. I have the following:

```
ostringstream ss;
char * memblock;
unsigned char x;
std::string hexFile;

ifstream file ("row.mid", ios::binary);
ofstream output;
output.open("output.txt");

while(file >> x){
    ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int) x;
}

hexFile = ss.str();
cout << hexFile;
```

When I output hexFile, I get the following (note the white space near the end):

```
4d546864000000060001000400f04d54726b0000001300ff58040402180800ff5103 27c000ff2f00
```

When I view the MIDI in a hex editor, it reads as follows:

```
4d546864000000060001000400f04d54726b0000001300ff58040402180800ff5103 0927c000ff2f00
```

The latter is definitely correct, as confirmed by track size (around the white space I manually inserted, the correct one has a 09 the former lacks).

What could have caused this `09` to go missing in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default ifstream skips whitespace.
All you need to do is tell it not to.

```
ifstream file ("row.mid", ios::binary);
file.unsetf(ios::skipws); //add this line to not skip whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

`09` is an ANSII code for tabulation character. The default `ofstream` mode is for text, and that's why the `09` byte is written as the actual tabulation. Try to set `ios::binary` also for the output file, and it should be fine.

```
output.open("output.txt", ios::binary);
```

Comment: I don't use the ofsteam (in this code segment, ideally write the string to output.txt later). I'm printing the actual string and it's lacking the 09;

Answer (score 0):

Appending the following line after declaring `ifstream file()` seems to do the trick:

```
file >> std::noskipws;
```